# How to style replace string character using regex?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, regex

Trying to style `|` delimited in the string buts its adding complete tag to string , any idea how can i achieve this task with plain Javascript ?

ctrl.js

```
var string = "[2017-07-12T12:38:36-04:00]|zsh458|info|<n/a>|[infra.actorRouter] Processing message from topic UEQ: 216014da-b849-4a1d-8232-3629e58338ce { partition: 0, offset: 12081530 }"

var message = string.replace(/\|/g,'<span class="pipe">|</span>');

console.log(message); //printing this 

[2017-07-12T12:38:36-04:00]<span class="pipe">|</span>zsh458<span class="pipe">|</span>info<span class="pipe">|</span><n/a><span class="pipe">|</span>[infra.actorRouter] Processing message from topic UEQ: 216014da-b849-4a1d-8232-3629e58338ce { partition: 0, offset: 12081530 }
```

Comment: Console is not purposed to show rendered HTML, only plain text.

Comment: Put `message` into the `innerHTML` of an element and you'll see it styled correctly.

Comment: @Barmar can you please provide answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the message into the DOM, not the console, to see the styling.

```js
var string = "[2017-07-12T12:38:36-04:00]|zsh458|info|<n/a>|[infra.actorRouter] Processing message from topic UEQ: 216014da-b849-4a1d-8232-3629e58338ce { partition: 0, offset: 12081530 }"

var message = string.replace(/\|/g, '<span class="pipe">|</span>');
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message;
```

```css
.pipe {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null, I am adding this span into incoming data from server that is displaying using ng-repeat, so my question is where we specifying `div` in that case , I can not add html tag inside div for this purpose

Comment: How were you adding the output to the DOM before you tried to add the styling? Just do it the same way. This was just a simple example.

Comment: this what i have on dom `<li ng-repeat="message in event.data track by $index">
                        <span  class="messageMargin" id="message">{{message.value}}</span>
 </li>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Angular, I don't know how to modify something that's added like that. You posted this as a Javascript question.